# Using multiple bootstrap buttongroups in one page

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Let's say I would like to have 2 different button groups on my page.

```
<div class="btn-group fruits" role="group" aria-label="fruits" id="fruits">
    <button type="button" name="fruits" class="btn btn-default">apple</button>
    <button type="button" name="fruits" class="btn btn-default">cherry</button>
    <button type="button" name="fruits" class="btn btn-default">melon</button>
</div>

<div class="btn-group vegetables" role="group" aria-label="vegetables" id="vegetables">
    <button type="button" name="vegetables" class="btn btn-default">cucumber</button>
    <button type="button" name="vegetables" class="btn btn-default">aubergine</button>
    <button type="button" name="vegetables" class="btn btn-default">pepper</button>
</div>
```

Whenever I click on a button, the selected button on other group became deselected.

I have added, different "ids", "names", "classes" to each buttongroup and button. But unfortunately no success. How can I have multiple buttongroups on a page without affecting eachother?

All the examples on official bootstrap page are even like that. When you click on o buttongroup, other buttongroup deselected. [Bootstrap Button Group](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups)

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: The behaviour you described is what is expected. are you trying to achieve to habe 2 buttons be "clicked" at the same time?

Comment: @nozzleman Yes. I exactly want to have 1 button clicked from one buttongoup, and another 1 button clicked from another buttongroup.

Comment: They're not radio fields thus there's no on/off state for those buttons. What you're chalking up to as "selected" is actually the "focus" state which is behaving as intended. To make them stateful, you need to use `<input type="radio"/>` elements with the necessary [plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you can do.

> [**Checkbox / Radio**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio)
>
> *Add data-toggle="buttons" to a .btn-group containing checkbox or radio inputs to enable toggling in their respective styles.*

```js
$('input').on('change', function () {
  console.clear();
  console.log(this.value)
})
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
body {
  margin: 12px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">

      <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default">
          <input type="radio" name="options" value="left" autocomplete="off"> Left
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
          <input type="radio" name="options" value="middle" autocomplete="off"> Middle
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
          <input type="radio" name="options" value="right" autocomplete="off"> Right
        </label>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">

      <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default">
          <input type="radio" name="options" value="left 2" autocomplete="off"> Left 2
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
          <input type="radio" name="options" value="middle 2" autocomplete="off"> Middle 2
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
          <input type="radio" name="options" value="right 2" autocomplete="off"> Right 2
        </label>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That Works. @David It seems impossible by using standart buttongroups. And one more thing.. How to get selected one from in your solution?

Comment: @oneNiceFriend I have made an edit. Just listen for `change` events on the `radio` input elements to get the selected one.