Bootstrap radio button group
I'm creating a form in Blazor and I like to have a segment like the following example

Using Bootstrap, I have this code for that
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
    <input type="radio" id="btnradio1-@Id" class="btn-check" name="btnradio1-@Id" 
        autocomplete="off" checked @bind-value="Value">
    <label class="form-label btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio1-@Id">
        Yes</label>

    <input type="radio" id="btnradio2-@Id" class="btn-check" name="btnradio2-@Id" 
        autocomplete="off" @bind-value="Value">
    <label class="form-label btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio2-@Id">
        No</label>

    <input type="radio" id="btnradio3-@Id" class="btn-check" name="btnradio3-@Id" 
        autocomplete="off" @bind-value="Value">
    <label class="form-label btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio3-@Id">
        Sometimes</label>
</div>

and in the code, I have this parameter:
[Parameter] public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
[Parameter] public string? Value { get; set; }

When I click on an input, I want to change the Value with the correspond value of the input I clicked. For example, if I click on No, I want that the Value is No.

Using html radio buttons to do this is a little problematic.  I've found it easier to build a custom InputBase component using the Bootstrap ButtonGroup with normal buttons.
Here's a simple version:
@using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis

@inherits InputBase<string>

<div class="btn-group mt-1 me-2 mb-3" data-toggle="buttons">
    @foreach( var item in this.Options)
    {
        <button type="button" class="@this.GetButtonCSS(item.Value)" @onclick="() => ValueHasChanged(item.Value)">
            @item.Value
        </button>
    }
</div> 

@code {
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public IEnumerable<SelectOption<string>> Options { get; set; } = Enumerable.Empty<SelectOption<string>>();
    [Parameter] public string SelectedCss { get; set; } = "btn btn-primary";
    [Parameter] public string UnSelectedCss { get; set; } = "btn btn-outline-primary";

    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string? value, out string result, [NotNullWhen(false)] out string? validationErrorMessage)
    {
        result = value ?? string.Empty;
        validationErrorMessage = null;
        return true;
    }

    private string GetButtonCSS(string value)
    {
        return value.Equals(this.Value)
            ? this.SelectedCss
            : this.UnSelectedCss;
    }

    private void ValueHasChanged(string value)
    {
        this.CurrentValueAsString = value;
    }
}

The option object:
public readonly record struct SelectOption<TValue>(TValue Value, string Label);

And a demo page:
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<EditForm Model="_model">
    <RadioButtonInput Options="_options" @bind-Value="_model.Value1" />
    <RadioButtonInput Options="_options" @bind-Value="_model.Value2" />
    <RadioButtonInput Options="_options" @bind-Value="_model.Value3" />
</EditForm>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>Value1: @_model.Value1</pre>
    <pre>Value2: @_model.Value2</pre>
    <pre>Value3: @_model.Value3</pre>
</div>

@code {
    private List<SelectOption<string>> _options = new() {
        new("Yes", "Yes"),
        new("No", "No"),
        new("Sometimes", "Sometimes")
    };

    private Model _model = new();

    public class Model
    {
        public string Value1 { get; set; } = "N";
        public string Value2 { get; set; } = "N";
        public string Value3 { get; set; } = "N";
    }
}



If I add in the same page 2 or more than them, the selection is not visible. I saw this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40996407/using-multiple-bootstrap-buttongroups-in-one-page that shows the same behaviour I get

Are you saying that if you use two or more of the components on the same page, the selection doesn't work?  I've updated my answer to show multiple controls working.

I think you have to add near data-toggle="buttons" also role="group"

You don't need them: that's stuff to make it work with Bootstrap's JS.  All interactivity in my component is dealt with by the Blazor component.  Incorporating the Bootstrap JS almost certainly causes concurrency issues with component state.  That's probably the cause of your problems.
